# reading batch of json files into dataframe

Tags: pyspark

All -

I have millions of single json files, and I want to ingest all into a Spark dataframe. However, I didn't see a `append` call, where I can append json as additions. Instead, the only way I can make it work is:

```
for all json files do:
    df_tmp = spark.read.json("/path/to/jsonfile", schema=my_schema)
    df = df.union(df_tmp)
```

`df` is the final aggregated dataframe. This approach works a few hundreds files, but as it approaches thousands, it is getting slower and slower. I suspect this cost of dataframe create and merge are signficant, and it feels awkward as well. Is there a better approach? TIA

Comment: You can just pass the path to the folder instead of individual file and it will read all the files in it. for eg `df_tmp = spark.read.json("/path/to/", schema=my_schema)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the path to the folder instead of individual file and it will read all the files in it.

For example, your files are in a folder called `JsonFiles`, you can write,

```
df = spark.read.json("/path/to/JsonFiles/")

df.show()
```